# Java Web Application read from file and write to same file

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

Ok, I have a web application that I have written and I can read from a file that I have included in my source package in a new folder named "text". I am trying to write to that same file, but it does not work. It never writes to the file. Here is the code for my two methods:

```
public void fillItems() throws IOException{
    String path = "/OBrien_PROJ2/text/catalog.txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path))); 
    String text = null;
    while ((text=br.readLine())!=null){
       String[] itemArray = text.split(","); 
       // you might want to check array size
       items.add(new ItemBean (itemArray[0], itemArray[1], itemArray[2], itemArray[3], itemArray[4]));

    }

    br.close();
}



 public void createNewItem(String iD, String name, String description, String price, String quantity) throws IOException{
     String path = "/OBrien_PROJ2/text/catalog.txt";
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
     bw.write(iD + "," + name + "," + description + "," + price + "," + quantity);
     items.add(new ItemBean (iD, name, description, price, quantity));
     bw.flush();
     bw.close();
 }
```

If it matters, I am using NetBeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` to get the current path of a web application

You Would better use this code that I have written right now

```
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <%
        try{
        String file = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"text/test.txt";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource you read is not a file. It's a resource loaded by the classloader. When deployed, this resource will be read from inside a war file, and perhaps even from a jar file inside this war file.

Don't ever try to modify the contents of a webapp dynamically. Even if it is possible, it's an extremely bad idea, since any redeployment of the webapp would delete the creted or modified files. If you have to write somewhere, write to a database (preferrably), since it can easily be shared by multiple webapp instances, and handle concurreny natively), or to a file outside of the webapp.

BTW, the argument of the FileWriter constructor is a file path. So `new FileWriter("/OBrien_PROJ2/text/catalog.txt")` writes to the file `/OBrien_PROJ2/text/catalog.txt` on the file system (and not inside the webapp).

Comment: I dont have the option of writing to a database. There is no way to write to text file contained in the webapp?

Comment: Short answer: no. Would you find it logical that a .exe file write something into itself? Same for a war file.

Answer (score 0):

First you will create two servlets. Here I create A and B servlets.

public class A extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        InputStream input= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("addressBook.txt");
        int x= input.read();
        while(x != -1){
            char c= (char) x;
            out.print(c);
            x= input.read();                
        }
     }
        catch(Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

here I write this text into addressBook.txt file.A servlet read the text file.
B servlet write the text file.

```
public class B extends HttpServlet {

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String name=request.getParameter("n");
        String mobile=request.getParameter("m"); 
        out.println(name+"<br>");
        out.println(mobile);
        FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter("E:\\IJSE\\ABSD\\DAY 6\\Assignment 1\\src\\java\\adbook.txt",true);
        PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(fileWriter,true);
        if(name==null||mobile==null) {
           } else {
                printWriter.println("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + mobile + "</td></tr>");
                out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#1589FF\">\n" +
                "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
                "alert( \"Added successfull\" );\n" +
                "</script>\n" +
                "<p></p>");

           }
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```